# Parametric equation of Mandelbrot curve on k-th iteration?

Tags: parametric, fractals, parametrization

Is there a way to write the parametric equation of the Mandelbrot-set's boundary curve at every $k^{th}$ iteration?

Comment: Do you mean this? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MandelbrotSetLemniscate.html

Comment: yes, this is what I'm think of

Comment: but where can I find the equation for it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Laurent Series for the conformal map from the complement of the unit disc to the complement of the Mandelbrot set](https://www.mrob.com/pub/muency/laurentseries.html), put in $w = r \exp(2 \pi i t)$ where $r > 1$ depends on $k$ (something like $r = 1 + 2^{-k}$, not sure of the exact formula).  But it is *very* slow to converge.